# How can I design a signal-safe shell interpreter

Tags: c, shell, signals

The code I have right now sends a prompt out to stdout, then reads a line from stdin. Receiving `SIGINT` at any point interrupts execution and exits the program. I am unsure where I should trap `SIGINT`, and I know that I cannot start a new prompt when the signal is received with my current code. Is there a proper way to accomplish that (ultimate goal would be for it to act like most shells (SIGINT cancels the current prompt and starts a new one))?

This code will run on Linux, but the less platform independent, the better.

`get_line` reads a line from stdin into a buffer and generates a char[], which is assigned to line.
`split_args` takes a line and transforms it into an array of char[], splitting on whitespace.
`is_command_valid` determines if the user typed a known internal command. External programs cannot be executed.

```
static int run_interactive(char *user)
{
    int done = 0;

    do
    {
        char *line, **args;
        int (*fn)(char *, char **);

        fprintf(stderr, "gitorium (%s)> ", user);
        get_line(&line);

        if (line[0] == '\0')
        {
            free(line);
            break;
        }

        split_args(&args, line);

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "quit") || !strcmp(args[0], "exit") ||
            !strcmp(args[0], "logout") || !strcmp(args[0], "bye"))
            done = 1;
        else if (NULL == args[0] ||
            (!strcmp("help", args[0]) && NULL == args[1]))
            interactive_help();
        else if ((fn = is_command_valid(args)) != NULL)
            (*fn)(user, args);
        else
            error("The command does not exist.");

        free(line);
        free(args);
    }
    while (!done);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the two most important helper functions

```
static int split_args(char ***args, char *str)
{
    char **res = NULL, *p = strtok(str, " ");
    int n_spaces = 0, i = 0;

    while (p)
    {
        res = realloc(res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);

        if (res == NULL)
            return GITORIUM_MEM_ALLOC;

        res[n_spaces-1] = p;
        i++;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * (n_spaces+1));
    if (res == NULL)
        return GITORIUM_MEM_ALLOC;

    res[n_spaces] = 0;
    *args = res;

    return i;
}

static int get_line(char **linep)
{
    char *line = malloc(LINE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    int len = LINE_BUFFER_SIZE, c;
    *linep = line;

    if(line == NULL)
        return GITORIUM_MEM_ALLOC;

    for(;;)
    {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if(c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;

        if(--len == 0)
        {
            char *linen = realloc(*linep, sizeof *linep + LINE_BUFFER_SIZE);
            if(linen == NULL)
                return GITORIUM_MEM_ALLOC;

            len = LINE_BUFFER_SIZE;
            line = linen + (line - *linep);
            *linep = linen;
        }

        *line++ = c;
    }

    *line = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific questions about a problem you're trying to solve. Questions that say "Here's what I want to do. You can see my code by going to my (some other site) and reading it." are closed quite quickly here. If you have a specific question to ask, post the relevant code *here* and ask a question about that code, and we can try and help you solve it. (The code should be here, because if your off-site location is unavailable for some reason the question becomes meaningless. It's also not searchable by future readers.) Thanks. :-)

Comment: As a meta tip: You might want to delete your question while you're rewording it, so as not to attract unnecessary close votes and downvotes. You can then undelete it when you've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to handle the signal as well as what to do once you get it.

The way you establish a signal handler is with [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). You didn't state the platform you're on so I'm assuming Linux, although `sigaction()` is defined by the POSIX standards and should be available on most other platforms.

There are various ways you can do this. One way is to establish a signal handler which simply sets a global variable to 1, denoting that the signal was caught. Then in your `getline()` function you establish a check to see if `SIGINT` was caught and if it was then return `NULL` and allow `run_interactive()` to run again.

Here's how you would catch the signal:

```
#include <signal.h>

static int sigint_caught = 0;

static void sigint_handler(int sig) {
  sigint_caught = 1;
}

struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0; // or SA_RESTART if you want to automatically restart system calls interrupted by the signal
sa.sa_handler = sigint_handler;

if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
  printf("could not establish handler\n");
  exit(-1); // or something
}
```

And then perhaps in `getline()`, in the infinite loop, you would establish the check to see if `SIGINT` has been caught:

```
for (;;) {
  if (sigint_caught) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // ...
```

And then in your `run_interactive()` call you can check the return value *with* the check to see if `SIGINT` was caught:

```
// ...

get_line(&line);

if (line == NULL && sigint_caught) {
  sigint_caught = 0; // allow it to be caught again
  free(line);
  continue; // or something; basically go to the next iteration of this loop
} else if (line[0] == '\0') {
  free(line);
  break;
} else {
  // rest of code
```

Didn't test it so I can't guarantee it'll work, since your question is pretty broad (having to look through more of your code etc.), but hopefully it gives you enough of an idea as to what you can do you in your situation. This is perhaps a pretty naive solution but it might meet your needs. For something more robust perhaps look into the source code for popular shells like bash or zsh.

For example, one thing that can happen is that `fgetc()` might block since there is no new data in stdin, and that might be when the signal is sent. `fgetc()` would be interrupted and `errno` would be `EINTR`, so you could add a check for this in `getline()`:

```
c = fgetc(stdin);

// make sure to #include <errno.h>
if (errno == EINTR && sigint_caught)
  return NULL;
```

This would only happen if you *don't* set `sa_flags` to `SA_RESTART`. If you do, then `fgetc` should automatically restart and continue blocking until new input is received, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: thanks. I added the code for the `get_line()` function. I will try this out. I tried reading the equivalent code for bash, but there were some parts that were either wholly too complex for me or that I didn't understand. I'll give it another go.

Comment: I managed to catch the signal, but I am not able to restart the input prompt.

Comment: @xav0989 You'll have to be more specific. What happens when the signal is caught? Did you read the last part of my post? It could be that `fgetc` is blocking if you set `SA_RESTART`. Perhaps don't set `SA_RESTART` to force interruption of `fgetc` when the signal is caught.

Comment: It seems like the application skips the "return null" section and instead sets the line string to an empty array, causing the application to think that it received no input, and thus can end.